# Return values as a matrix in R using outer()

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I'm attempting to extract interspecific distances from a genetic distance matrix.

Since the distance matrix is symmetric by definition, values above and below the main diagonal are repeated.

To fix this, I use `upper.tri` to subset the larger matrix.

Here is an MWE:

```
# install.packages("ape")
library(ape)

data(woodmouse)
dists <- dist.dna(woodmouse, model = "raw", as.matrix = TRUE)
isSymmetric(dists) # TRUE
dists[upper.tri(dists, diag = FALSE)] <- NA # replace upper triangle with NA and then subset to get lower triangular matrix
isSymmetric(dists) # FALSE
dists # this is a matrix

labs <- labels(woodmouse) # get species names 

res <- outer(labs, labs, "==") # cases where matrix elements are equal
inter <- na.omit(dists[!res]) # get interspecific distances by taking elements that are not equal
```

The above code works fine; however, `inter` is a vector instead of a matrix.

Ideally, I'm needing to extract the interspecific values of `dists` while ensuring a matrix is still returned. That is, have the same structure as `dists`.

Does someone know of a good solution?

Please let me know if anything is unclear and I will clarify.

Comment: What would be the expected output? Maybe a `sparseMatrix` is what you need: `library(Matrix); 
dists[is.na(dists)] <- 0;
as(dists, "sparseMatrix")`

Comment: It seems the only value res is TRUE is for the `diag`onal, so you can simplify the problem thre

Comment: Maybe just do `is.na(dists) <- res`. Or, since that just removes the diagonal, why not `dists[upper.tri(dists, diag = TRUE)] <- NA`? Or even switch to sparse matrices.